# Not able to go after the login. It works only in recovery mode. How to check what is wrong?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 18.04, login

I recently (less than 24h ago) reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer. I don't know if it's relevant but I also have Windows 10 on it.

The strange fact is that right after I login in Ubuntu everything stops: the screen is eggplant color, the mouse doesn't work and no icon is present. I can go back to the login page with `ctrl` + `\` but I can't do anything from there.

If I launch Ubuntu in recovery mode, check the file system or check for broken dependencies everything seems fine. Also, if a continue the boot from recovery mode (the system specify that I will not able to use some graphic driver unless I reboot properly) the system works. Of course, the resolution of the screen is messed up but I'm able to ask for help.

For this reasons, I think that something in my graphic drivers is messed up. My question is:

How could I check what is wrong right now in my installation? How could I correct it?

---

I take back something that I wrote previously. Now I'm not able to run fsck anymore. This is what I get if I try to run it in the recovery menu:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/reS: no such file or directory fsck from util-linux 2.31.1

/dev/sda5 is mounted

e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting
```

---

It really seems only a graphic driver problems. However, I still don't understand the error with fsck.

Comment: You're probably right about the graphics drivers. Some Nvidia cards require proprietary drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Why in my previous boots I hadn't problems then?

Comment: I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GabrielaGarcia's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090424/not-able-to-go-after-the-login-it-works-only-in-recovery-mode-how-to-check-wha#comment1794344_1090424) I found out that I didn't selected the corrected graphic card drivers.

If you don't have the Nvidia repository you could add it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and install the drivers with apt (e.g. with `nvidia-340`, check which is the one you should use on Nvidia website):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

In my case I already had them installed, so I just selected the recommended one. To select the graphic driver, go to Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and select the one you want.